# Laravel Scheduling call controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I work with Laravel Task Scheduling, but I have a problem when I call some method from my controller.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call('UserController@deleteInactiveUsers')->everyMinute();
    //$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\UserController@deleteInactiveUsers')->everyMinute();
}
```

When I call with uncommented line i get this error:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class RecurrenceInvoiceController does not exist
```

and then I insert fully qualified namespace path and then I get this error:

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

And

```
[ErrorException] PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Where is the problem? Which way is correct to call method from Controller from Laravel Task Scheduling.

Comment: What `QUEUE_DRIVER` are u using inside your .env file?

Comment: In my `.env` file -> `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`

Answer (score 41):

I use Laravel 5.2 and the kernel calls my drivers this way:

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\MyController@MyAction')->everyMinute();
```

Comment: @BinitGhetiya How did you add parameter option?

Comment: although this answer solve the OP problem but i really think that the cron should call a service function not a controller one, i would put the logic you have in that controller function inside a service and i will call it from the controller and the cron

Answer (score 3):

Directly put this in schedule function in `kernel.php`.

`$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\YourController@function')->everyMinute();`

This will run after every minute.

Note:

In localhost, you have to run it manually but on the server, you should try this command in your cronjob this will automatically call your controller function after every minute

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/iflasity/public_html/foldername /artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1 

cd /home/iflasity/public_html/foldername && php artisan schedule:run /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the first error looks like you need to run `composer update`, then `composer dump-autoload`.

If it works you will also get the second error, the 2002 error meaning is:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" (see (Client Error Codes and Messages in MySQL docs).

You need to set your database configuration in your `.env` file

Comment: Because controller is wrong way to use in scheduling task, I created artisan Command with same logic from my Controller. But now I don't gave any error message but don't work this functionality.
Also I create route for this controller to test this code and code work perfectly, but there not.

Comment: My `.env` file is OK because I successfully inserted record in database from controller but from scheduling not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Docker Cron container. Cron container was not linked with MySQL container.

Answer (score 0):

Also now I test with more simple function to insert new currency in database. Here is code:

```
public function handle()
{
    $currency = new Currency();
    $currency->currency_name = 'EUR';
    $currency->save();

    $this->info('New currency is successfully generated!');
}
```

This function is from `laravel/app/Console/Commands`. I call from `Kernel > schedule()`. Not work.

When I insert simple log write to `handle()` function like:

```
File::put(base_path() . '/storage/logs/test_logs.txt', 'Test log ' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL);
```

this works. But when I try to create new object from `Models` and save into db -> this not work.

Comment: I test this code row by row. First 2 row where I create new `Currency` object and add property `currency_name` is OK. But the error is on row 3, where I call save method. `$currency->save()`

Comment: This is not an answer, so, for proper use of stackoverflow you should edit your question and put any new information there, on the other hand your are adding a lot of blurry informatión, what are you trying to do? an artisan command? calling a controller? running a task? please! stick with one so we can work from something.