# Laravel cronjob run what's inside the method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my controller i have these method where it checks for url status

```
public function index(){
    $url = Url::latest()->paginate();
    return UrlsResource::collection($url);
}
```

my `UrlsResource` return data like this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'url' => $this->url,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d'),
     ];
}
```

where in the `$this->status` is an accessor from my model.

```
public function getStatusAttribute(){ 
    $handle = curl_init($this->url);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($handle);
    $message = [
        '100' => '(100) Continue '. $this->url, 
        '101' => '(101) Switching Protocols '. $this->url, 
        '102' => '(102) Processing '. $this->url, 
     ];
    return $message[$httpCode];
}
```

How can I run a cronjob where in I want to run what's inside my index method?

I tried to make a command where in

```
class CheckUrl extends Command
{
protected $signature = 'check:url';
protected $description = 'Check url';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $url = Url::latest()->paginate();
        UrlsResource::collection($url);
    }
}
```

and i tried to run it via command line

```
php artisan check:url
```

but nothing happened

it says on the documentation that add this cron entry to server

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but i dont know exactly where to put it (im using xampp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Scheduling call controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038241/laravel-scheduling-call-controller)

Comment: run `php artisan` verified if you command show here

Comment: I verified it and it shows there.

Comment: try this put dd on your index and next you command `$test= new jobsController(); $test->index();` and try if you command execute

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? i could not see any benefit of cron job.

Comment: Are you using any server or doing at your local machine?

Comment: local machine sir

Comment: im trying to check the http code of a specific url by using cron job so i want to use what is inside my method to cron

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the controller@method as a string to call().

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\MyController@MyAction')->everyMinute();
```

Comment: $schedule->command('check:url')->everyMinute(); but when i run it with php artisan schedule:run im getting Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" check:url > "NUL" 2>&1

Comment: Try doing $schedule->call with your Controller string in it.

Comment: i tried it this should be texting me after 1 min but nothing happened

Comment: Is there anything in your storage/logs/laravel.log ?

Comment: my laravel.log looks like these 
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bapp\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 {main}
"}

Answer (score -1):

you can call any method from your controller to the scheduler like that

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\yourController@index')->everyMinute()
```

but you need to add your scheduler command to corntab so the task can be executed.

run in terminal

```
crontab -e
```

and past this command

```
 * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```